# Standard error of proportion in surveys with replicate weights

Tags: stata, interpretation, survey

I'm examining some proportions in some CPS data.  Here's my output:

```
Survey: Proportion estimation    Number of obs    =     208562
                                 Population size  =  293834358
                                 Subpop. no. obs  =      10268
                                 Subpop. size     =   10852852
                                 Replications     =        160

      _prop_1: hcovany = Not covered

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |                 SDR
             | Proportion   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
hcovany      |
     _prop_1 |   .0688032   .0043297      .0603171    .0772893
     Covered |   .9311968   .0043297      .9227107    .9396829
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I list the e(V_srssub) matrix I see 6.240e-06 which equals (.93*.06)/10268.  However, the square root is .00249794 which does not match the standard error displayed above.  Can someone explain why and how I can save the proper standard error?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The report SDR **is** the proper standard error. `e(V_srssub)` is a unicorn of simple random sampling, and it is meaningless in most analysis -- it is only used to compute the design effect.

Comment: @StasK Ok, that makes sense.  Is the SDR saved somewhere?  Can it be retrieved?

Comment: Stata commands save results which can be retrieved using `return` and `ereturn`. See `help return` for details. Stata commands, in their help files, describe what is saved where. `help proportion` states that co(variances) are saved in `e(V)`.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Yes, before I posted I used ereturn to list all of the matrices. Just didn't realize e(V) contained what I needed. Taking the square root yields the SE.